# How does one pronounce "Asshai"?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, pronunciation

How exactly do you pronounce "Asshai" from  A Song of Ice and Fire? I always pronounced it "ash-shy" but one of my friends says that it's "ass-high". Can anyone tell me the correct pronunciation?

Comment: With great difficulty.

Comment: I always thought it was "[asshair](http://blogoficeandfire.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/catelyn-daenerys.html)". Lol.

Comment: @Mooz I see "asshat" myself. :P

Comment: Might as well throw in “as-shy” and “ass-shy” as options too.

Comment: I've always pronounced in uh-shy

Comment: Cearly, it's "ASS-high."

Answer (score 9):

In audiobooks, *Asshai* is pronounced as **ASH-eye** or **a-SHY**, depending on the narrator's accent.

In the HBO's show *Game of Thrones*, it is pronounced as **uh-SHY**.

For your reference, you may check these pronunciation guides:

- [A Wiki of Ice and Fire (Pronunciation Guide)](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pronunciation_guide)
- [Official Pronunciation Guide of Game of Thrones](https://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/2011/2/11/official-pronunciation-guide-for-game-of-thrones.html)

Answer (score 7):

Consult with the following table:

| Source | IPA | Pronunciation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HBO | [ə'ʃaɪ] | ə-shy |
| Roy Dotrice (Audio books narrator) | [a'ʃaɪ] | a-shy |
| John Lee (Audio book narrator for AFFC) | ['aʃaɪ] | ash-eye |

You can refer to [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/is-there-an-online-tool-to-convert-ipa-symbols-into-audio-sound) to see how can you convert IPA to voice. The table was generated as per [AWOIAF Pronunciation guide](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pronunciation_guide). I will add GRRM's version once I can find a video of him saying that word.

Comment: What is the upside down e?

Comment: It is a schwa.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa

Comment: @user00001 [See IPA symbols for English language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects)

Comment: I'm always surprised to hear GRRM pronounce Doth-rak-eye

Answer (score 4):

## However you like

George R. R. Martin has never been one for pronunciations and has said a few times that you can pronounce anything however you like.

> *Favorite character?*
>
> GRRM : Tyrion in Ice and Fire. Abner Marsh in Fevre Dream.
>
> *Glad to hear you pronounce the names*
>
> GRRM: In my youth I had a strong NJ accent, only reader in family, knew a lot of words that I had never heard spoken aloud. When I went away to college I found I was pronouncing a lot of these words wrong. **I came to not care much about pronunciation. Pronounce the names of my characters however you like.**
>
> There are dangers in being a gardener, the story can run away from you - Shakespeare had to kill Mercutio because he was taking over play.
>
> <sub>[So Spake Martin, ODYSSEY CON 2008 (MADISON, WI; APRIL 4-6 2008)](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Odyssey_Con_2008_Madison_WI_April_4_6_20081)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Characters in the TV show pronounce it *ass-shy* or *ah-shy*.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for your answer? It is recommended that you support your answer with as much evidence to show proof your answer is valid and not just an assumption you've made.

Comment: The TV show is my source...

Comment: I've never heard them say Ass-shy. Can you provide a YouTube clip or something?